# Initializing random 2D matrix with pointers in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want my matrix to look the following:

```
1 2 3
X X X
X X X
```

When X is a random number.

I tried the following:

```
void initMat(int *mat, int rows, int cols)
{
   *(mat + 0) = 1;
   *(mat + 1) = 2;
   *(mat + 2) = 3;
   for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols - 3; i++)
   {
       *(mat + 3) = rand() % 6;
       mat++;
   }
}
```

and I call the function:

```
 initMat((int *)startValues, 3, 3);
```

When I print my matrix with the following function:

```
void printMat(const int *mat, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            printf("%4d", *mat);
            mat++;
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I get something that look like 2D array, as I actually wanted, for example:

```
startValues:
   1    2    3
   4    1    5
   4    4    5
```

But when I try to print it with (In the same main, after the matrix was initiated)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%4d", startValues[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

I get:

```
VALUES:

   1   2   3
   3   4   1
   1   5   2
```

Why does it happen? Why the values are different and some look the same. How should I reach each value? I tried also using the formula:

```
m+ cols*i + j //(in my case startValues + 3*i+j in the last loop)
```

But it gives me very large random numbers and I'm not really sure when do I need to use it instead of mat[i][j].

Comment: Off by one. Please change the end condition in `i <= rows * cols - 3;` to `i < rows * cols - 3;`

Comment: @WeatherVane Changed.

Comment: Aside: please don't make "interactive progress updates" to the code posted.

Comment: Can't reproduce from "imagined" code that includes your snippets. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. Are you passing the *incremented* `mat` to another function?

Comment: @WeatherVane This is the code I just made splits to explain. What you mean by incremented mat?

Comment: Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example as text, the shortest complete code that shows what you have tried. We can't guess what the rest of the code is doing. Note that you have `mat++` so the value passed is no longer what it was. Are you passing that to another function? We don't have all the code. the code you posted behaves when copy/pasted into my "guess" of what the rest of the code is. The post has no libraries, no `main()`. Please post code that can be copy/pasted, compiled and run *as is* to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using pointer to Variable-Length Array (VLA). It makes code far more readable:

```
void initMat(int rows, int cols, int mat[static rows][cols])
{
   mat[0][1] = 1;
   mat[0][2] = 1;
   mat[0][3] = 1;

   for (int r = 1; r < rows; r++)
   for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        mat[r][c] = rand() % 6;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to fill the matrix in the way I tried and to understand why it gives me different results in each way of printing. Maybe I'll your offer but still I can't understand the output of my code. Moreover, your function gives me an error of "a parameter is not allowedC/C++(411)"

Comment: @Ciniminis, what compiler are you using, what C standard is it?

Comment: @Ciniminis, issue with observing different result with each print cannot be addressed without reproducing the error. Please prepare a minimal program that shows such a behaviour? Or at least tell how `startValues` is declared